# Custom keyboard shortcut to paste a pre-defined text?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

I've been working on several website designs lately, and it looks like I'll be making a lot more in the near future. I find myself browsing to lipsum.com and copying a handful of paragraphs of random text to fill a design almost daily. I was wondering, is there any way I can set up a keyboard shortcut that will always paste a certain text, for instance a few paragraphs of lorem ipsum that I saved in a text file or something?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Autohotkey will do exactly that (although there are many similar apps). See http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm for your specific requirements

Comment: Cool, thanks. Will check it out and mark as an answer if it works out :)

Comment: Symantec suspected that it is a malicious program. I was skeptical but wish to try. It is pretty powerful as it is allows programming in Visual Basic. Very useful for developers like me who type the same code repeatedly.

Comment: This answer would be much more useful if it actually showed *how* to use Autohotkey to do this

Answer (score 23):

1. Create .bat file
2. Insert below text
   `clip < "myemail.txt"`
3. Create myemail.txt file and write your content
4. [Create shortcut](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-desktop-shortcut-for-an-office-program-or-file-9a8df64b-cd87-4700-95cc-4bc3e2a962da) and [assign short key](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/93130-how-assign-keyboard-shortcut-shortcuts-windows-10-a.html#option1) for the batch file shortcut
5. When ever you want paste the content press the short cut key , it will copy the text into clipboard, just have to paste the text.
   .txt,.bat create any where but short send to desktop and assign short key.

[image: screenshot showing to edit the properties of a shortcut to assign a Shortcut Key]

Comment: That's a great solution, I'll try and test it later today. Thanks.

Comment: I can't edit your post, but number 2 should be - Insert below the following text: clip < "myemail.txt". Otherwise it's not clear enough.

Comment: Complete instruction - http://www.yourtechtamer.com/blog/2011/08/can-you-create-a-shortcut-to-auto-paste-your-email-address-onto-the-clipboard/

Comment: Nice solution Azhar, handy for my 26 letter work domain name.