# Shortcut to paste text not from clipboard

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a shortcut key similar to `Ctrl + V`, which pastes a particular text (which is not in clipboard).
So, if I deal with my email address a lot, instead of typing it, can I configure a shortcut, for ex., `Ctrl + Shift + V`, so it always pastes my email address.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom keyboard shortcut to paste a pre-defined text?](http://superuser.com/questions/238402/custom-keyboard-shortcut-to-paste-a-pre-defined-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Mac, the easiest way to do this is to setup auto text expanders in Settings/Keyboard/Text. So `a@` and then spacebar could fill in your e-mail, for example.

On Windows [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org) is best for this, and many, many other things. Be sure to use the http://ahkscript.org address and not the one that comes up first in Google, it is an outdated and unsupported commercialized version. You will have to learn some very basic scripting language but it's not hard, should take just an hour or so.