# Custom keyboard shortcut to paste a pre-defined text?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, macros, text-editing, macro-button

I am finding myself with a lot of need to frequently type one of several specific short strings of text, and i'm growing very tired of the repetitive motions needed to do each.

What I would like to be able to do is bind some keys on my keyboard, so that whenever i simply press that key, it types the string of text i've pre-programmed.
In this case i'd like to use my numpad keys, i won't miss those

I found this site through a google search for this problem, and I found an old post from 7 years ago that seemed to answer this
[Custom keyboard shortcut to paste a pre-defined text?](https://superuser.com/questions/238402/custom-keyboard-shortcut-to-paste-a-pre-defined-text)

I found an answer there involving batch files which sounded perfect, but I can't seem to get it working, and i'm not sure if thats my fault. For my first test case, i wanted to make numpad 1 insert the text "/imagine prompt:"

So i created a batch file containing this

```
clip < "imagine.txt"
```

In the same folder, a text file containing

```
/imagine prompt:
```

And a shortcut to the batch file, setup within windows like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBC7x.png)

As far as I understand this should have been sufficient to make it so that when i press numpad 1, it pastes that text. It doesn't seem to be happening

Can anyone clarify if i'm doing anything wrong? Or offer alternative methods to achieve my goal? I'm not hugely attached to this batch file idea, whatever works. I intend to make several more similar macros like this once i can figure out a workable method

Comment: Just in case anyone finds this question through google in future & needs a solution for Mac; it's built-into the OS, but uses user-defined keywords, like `myeml` to trigger. It can generate long, formatted paragraphs if you copy/paste into it rather than type in manually.. System Prefs > Keyboard > Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question here:

A few days ago, someone posted an answer here which worked for me. That answer was to use PhraseExpress, it seems to work well enough
https://www.phraseexpress.com/download/

I don't see that answer here now, its possible the poster deleted it
It's also possible that I read it somewhere else and am misremembering

But here is the answer nevertheless, and thank you to whoever told me about it